# Trigger stored procedure from Java code and run it in background

Tags: sql, multithreading, parallel-processing, procedure

Is it possible to call a stored procedure from my Java code and then continue the normal flow/execution of my program, wth the procedure running in the background? Can I just trigger the procedure such that it goes on running in the background (can take 15-20 min) ?

Can we implement it using threads? If yes, how to go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
public class HelloThread extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        //call proc here
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        (new HelloThread()).start();
    }

}
```

[Taken from here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)

Answer (score 1):

Mainly you want your ui to be responsive despite a long running database operation you can use thread as suggested by lCarus

Answer (score 1):

Basically yes, you'll need to spawn off another Thread to make the call.  So I guess the next question is how - which will depend on the environment you're working in.  If you're in a Java EE environment, then maybe look at something like queues to run a process out of band.  Otherwise maybe look at the answer from Icarus, or if you need tie it back in with the thread of execution afterwards, maybe look at the concurrency utils - overview here maybe:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/concurrency/overview.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) to program a Job execution -that launches your stored procedure- independent of your program flow. You should give it a try.